# Run a different executable string in Gulp depending on OS

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to use the same gulp file on Windows and Mac and every task works fine except for one: when I need to execute an external process. I wonder if it's possible to somehow chose the task used based on OS?

On Mac I'm using `gulp-shell`

```
gulp.task('task-name', ['previous-task-name'],
    shell.task([
        '' //executable string
    ])
);
```

And on Windows `exec`

```
gulp.task('task-name', ['previous-task-name'], function(cb)
{
    exec('', //executable string
        function(err, stdout, stderr)
        {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            cb(err);
        });
});
```

Comment: Have you done anything with the variable `process.platform`?

Comment: Nope, I know nothing about this actually. So I imagine `process.platform` will give me OS, could you please refer the way to run a different task depending on the result of this variable?

Comment: It's returns a string, I don't know the details since I haven't done anything with gulp. But for something like windows you might be able to do: `if (process.platform == "win32"){/*do stuff
*/}`. [Here's the official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform).

Comment: @ArkinSolomon thank you! With this variable I just used a simple condition without using any additional plugins